# Comparing corpus complexities

Tags: measurement, natural-language

I would like to compare how complex (varied or predictable) are my three 
corpora. They are from different topics, so some vocabulary is different,
some is the same. Looking at one of the data sets it's clear that the syntax is more difficult than in the other two, sentences are longer, etc. I built word 
N-Gram language models using the SRILM toolkit (I'm new to language modelling) 
with the idea that I can then compare these models. One measure mentioned 
in relation to language models is perplexity. I'm confused about the following
question: Can I just use perplexities of the three LMs directly as a measure
of how varied are the corpora? The vocabulary and the sizes of the corpora
are different, so now I think that this won't be a good comparison. I also built
LMs from POS-Tags but the quality of the POS-Tagging result is not good because the language is from fora, has spelling mistakes, ungrammatical sentences and so on. What measures could be used to
compare complexity of corpora from different domains? 
I'd appreciate your advise.

Comment: Here is info about SRILM:  http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/

Comment: This Q has languished here for a week without activity.  Maybe it would fare better at http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/    which seem to also encompass computational linguistics?

Answer (score 0):

Perpelxity is a good measure of how predictable your text corpora are. For example, if the perplexity of you text is 80 then that means that predicting the next word in a sentence after reading the previous words is as hard as a multiple choice exam with 80 choices per question.

Comparing perplexities across corpora works best when you use the same vocabulary everywhere. You can specify a vocabulary when you build the language models in SRILM. You might want to use the same vocabulary for all of the files.